# Drop down box changes value automatically according to another drop down box in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint

I am working on SharePoint .I have two drop downcolumn in SharePoint list ,I have a condition like if the user selects a value as"bps" in first drop down box then second Dropbox should automatically changed to yes Can any one help me out with script

Answer (score 0):

Sample script for classic view,update the field title to yours(OptionA&OptionB)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {            
            $('select[Title="OptionA"]').change(function () {                
                if ($(this).val()=="bps") {
                    $('select[Title="OptionB"]').val("Yes");
                }
            })
        })
    </script>
```